# Get specific columns based on relational tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

My current tables that I have is related with translation.

```
Languages:
- id;
- name;

Products:
- id;
- online;
- price;

Products_Translations:
- id;
- product_id;
- name;
- description;
- language_id;
```

But there are 2 things that I'm trying to do. First thing is that I have a page that I retrieve all my products, and could do it easily creating in my Model `Product` the relation with the `Products_Translations` and get the information. Then would be just a case of working with it in a foreach loop.

But I think a better scenario would be having all the products information in the same query and then retrieve all the information one a collection of objects where I would have from the `product` table the 'online', 'price' and from the table products_translation the 'name', 'description' and 'language_id'.

My previous code was like

**Controller:**

```
$products = Product::all();
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($products as $product)
     @foreach($product->translatedProducts as $prod)

        some code

     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Product model:**

```
public function translatedProducts() {
    return $this->hasMany(ProductTranslation::class);
}
```

In this approach, my products information is kind of split in different places. The ideal scenario would be just in my case in the controller calling the products and receive all the collections objects with all the products details together.

I used this solution:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
            ->join('product_translations', 'products.id', '=', 'product_translations.product_id')
            ->select('products.*', 'product_translations.name', 'product_translations.description','product_translations.description','product_translations.locale')
            ->get();
```

But would be much more elegant use this logic instead on a controller but in a Model Product

Answer (score 0):

according to your info in question, I assume that Product and Language model has a ManyToMany relationship meaning that a product has many languages and a language has many product. So you do not need involve another translation term to confuse laravel. 
please do following steps:

I suggest you to create your model and migration files together:

```
php artisan make:model --migration Product
```

which will create `products` table also with first character lowercase.

```
php artisan make:model --migration Language
```

which will create both `Language` model and `languages` table.
and also create the pivot table: please note that pivot table is `product_language` and not `Products_Translations`

second in your models define followings:

In Product model:

```
public function languages(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class)->withPivot('name', 'description');
}
```

and in your Language model:

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('name', 'description');
}
```

now your setup is complete. 
If you want to have the products with all its `languages` relationship then you need to:

```
$products = Product::with('languages')->get();
```

This will eager-load the relationships. You can refer to laravel docs regarding eager loading.

now in your template you can have:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @foreach($product->languages as $language)
        //code here
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you want to get a column in a pivot table (`language_product`) then you can use:

```
$product->pivot->name;
```

or

```
$language->pivot->name;
```

another method can be to create a LanguageProduct model which has oneToMany relationship which `Product` and `Languages` models but I suggest the first choice. It is more elegant and laravel offers many methods for it.

I hope my answer suits your needs. IF any question let me know. I am here to answer.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem using [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) and then [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby) with `whereIn`.

**Controller:**

```
$products = Product::all();
$products_id = $products->pluck('id');
$transls = ProductsTranslations::where('language_id', $lang_id)
                                ->whereIn('id', $likeable_id)
                                ->get()
                                ->groupBy('product_id');
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $transls[$product->id][0]->name }} {{ $transls[$product->id][0]->description }}
@endforeach
```